# Is it possible to have top bar on UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I would like to present a `UIView` with standart top bar - Black Navigation Bar for the title of the UIView.

1. I have created a xib.
2. Set the top bar to be Black Navigation Bar in the xib
3. Added it to the screen:

   ```
   _popup = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Popup" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

   CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
   _popupBackground = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:
                       CGRectMake(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height)];
   _paymentPopupBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

   [_paymentPopupBackground addSubview:_popup];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:_paymentPopupBackground];
   ```
4. The `UIView` appeared but without the Black Navigation Bar. How can that be fixed?

Comment: `2.Set the top bar to be Black Navigation Bar`, actually you didn't. If you look carefully it says `Simulated Metrics`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation bar is for UIViewControllers not UIViews.You can use toolbar on top of the view and present it

make style black opaque

[image]

Comment: Great! Is it possible to make it look like Black Navigation Bar?

Answer (score 0):

To have a navigationBar you just need to embed the viewController within `UINavigationController`. Then you can set the tintColor of navigationController for the appearance you want.

Comment: I am pinning the UIView directly to the window. There is no viewController envolved in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a UINavigationBar to a UIView, but the setting in Interface Builder doesn't actually do anything if the UIViewController is not in a navigation stack.

Manually drag a UINavigationBar into your UIView.

Just to let you know, this probably isn't going to give your users a consistent experience, and may not make it through the review process - if you need a navigation bar, I'd strongly suggest having a navigation stack.

Comment: It looks like Lithu T.V's answer is more suitable in this case. What do you think?

Comment: I agree, a UIToolbar is by far the more appropriate control to use for a UIView.  It's all down to what the control will be used for, and a UIView has no need for a UINavigationBar.     As a side note, if you do need a navigation stack, but only in a portion of the screen, you can achieve this quite easily - in this scenario, a tool bar wouldn't be appropriate.